# Better way to filter a route by query parameter?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

In a Laravel 4.2 project, I have the following route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api/v' . Config::get('api.version')], function () {
    if (Input::get('api_key') != Config::get('api.key')) {
        App::abort(401, 'Invalid API key!');
    }

    // Do stuff below...
});
```

This is accessed by:

```
http://domain.com/api/v1/do-stuff/value1/value2?api_key=2fl2bkqg2yqlf2l872qa
```

This works great for users to access the API with their key. However, when I run `php artisan migrate --seed` it triggers that `api_key` restriction.

Is there a better way of restricting my route group by API key in Laravel that won't cause this issue with migrations?

Comment: Are you seeding your DB by pushing data through the API? Can you not push directly into the DB?

Comment: No, it is pushed directly to the database for seeding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the route group is created, the API check is run instantly despite no route in the group being triggered. You can add the logic to a filter leaving the group to hold just the routes to avoid this and have the api check executed only when a route is filtered by it.

```
Route::filter("api", function()
{
    if (Input::get('api_key') != Config::get('api.key')) 
    {
        return App::abort(401, 'Invalid API key!');
    }
});
```

Then in your route group remove the inline code and add the filter

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/v1', 'before' => 'api'), function()
{
    // Routes here
});
```

As these are filters, they are disabled for unit tests. As the filter is only ever run when a route is executed in this group, artisan commands won't trigger the api check when the route group is created.